# change billing and shipping address 1 and 2 field placeholders

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to change the placeholder text for the billing and shipping address 1 and address 2 fields but I can't get it to change at all. This is what I have for billing address 1

```
// This function sets the address 1 placeholder
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'uwc_new_address_one_placeholder' );
function uwc_new_address_one_placeholder($fields){

        $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['placeholder'] = 'over the hill';

    return $fields;
}
```

This works for every other field except for address 1 and 2. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to the address fields being passed through the `woocommerce_checkout_fields` hook, they are retrieved by `WC_Countries::get_address_fields()`, and inside *that* function there is a comment before its filter that reads:

> Important note on this filter: Changes to address fields can and will
>   be overridden by the woocommerce_default_address_fields. The
>   locales/default locales apply on top based on country selection. If
>   you want to change things like the required status of an address
>   field, filter woocommerce_default_address_fields instead.

It seems likely to me that the same issue would affect the `woocommerce_checkout_fields` filter.

So my recommendation would be to use the `woocommerce_default_address_fields` filter instead:

```
function uwc_new_address_one_placeholder( $fields ) {
    $fields['address_1']['placeholder'] = 'over the hill';

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'uwc_new_address_one_placeholder' );
```

Note that this filter applies to both shipping and billing addresses, and should not require the `shipping_` or `billing_` prefixes on the field names.